# get evernote's reminder with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, evernote

i want to get evernote's reminder using javascript. Searching and [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48080736/tasker-compatible-javascript-or-tasker-java-function-equivalent-from-this-codes/48083032#48083032), i got to the following code:

```
var token = 'yourToken':
var Evernote = require('evernote');

const nFilter = new Evernote.NoteStore.NoteFilter({
  words: "reminderOrder:*",
  ascending: true,
});

const rSpec = {};
rSpec.includeTitle = true;

var client = new Evernote.Client({token: token, sandbox: false});
var noteStore = client.getNoteStore();

noteStore.findNotesMetadata(nFilter, 0, 50, rSpec, function(notesMetadataList) {
  console.log("Found " + notesMetadataList.notes.length + " notes with `reminderOrder` set.");
  console.log();
  console.log("Here are their titles: ");

  for (var i in notesMetadataList.notes) {
    console.log("\t" + notesMetadataList.notes[i].title);
  }
});
```

Everything goes fine until the last part: `noteStore.findNotesMetadata(...`. I got this error:

```
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): #<ThriftException>
(node:1) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is my first nodejs code, so i don't know what i'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of `Evernote` you are using, but the latest is using promises and you should use the function like this instead:

```
noteStore.findNotesMetadata(nFilter, 0, 50, rSpec).then(function(notesMetadataList) {
    console.log("Found " + notesMetadataList.notes.length + " notes with `reminderOrder` set.");
    console.log();
    console.log("Here are their titles: ");

    for (var i in notesMetadataList.notes) {
      console.log("\t" + notesMetadataList.notes[i].title);
    }
  }).catch(function(err){
      console.log('Error:',err);
  });
```

The gist you linked is 2 years old, and most likely used callbacks.

Comment: I know, that why i changed it,but it appears i did it wrong, I'll try your suggestion and let you know

Comment: OK, that fixed it, but now i get a new error: `TypeError: "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer`

Comment: rSpec = {}  may need some inputs, did you clear that out on purpose?

Comment: I defined it right below: `rSpec.includeTitle = true;`

Comment: Unforunately I can't help you with that error as it's a little too vague for me. Did it give you a line number? Did it come from the .catch() we just created?

Comment: it's ok, i figured out!!